# get phone locale settings with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, locale

Does anyone know of a way to get the phones locale settings for android and ios using javascript?

I found this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization Which looks like will do it, but I'm looking for a why without using any libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
 alert(language);
```

Comment: Hmm, that was easy. looks like it's working for android. I immagine it will for android too.